# absence of value in javascript (undefined)

Tags: javascript, undefined, keyvaluepair, object-properties

I have list of objects with key value & pair.when I am separating those to display each information on a specific field .
I am getting type error **data.validation[i].user** is undefined
But I have checked the variables have been assigned a value.

```
var data = {validation:[
{"user":"user may not be empty"},
{"date":"Date may not be null"},
{"mobile":"passengerMobile may not be empty"},
{"mobileSize":"passengerMobile size must be greater than 11"},
{"name":"passengerName may not be empty"},
{"nameSize":"passengerName size must be between 2 and 30"},
 ]};

var size = data.validation.length;

for(var i =0;i<=size;i++){
if(data.validation[i].user){
 $("#username").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].user+"</p>");
  }
  if($("#mobile").val().length == 0){
    $("#mobilesize").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].mobile+"</p>");
    }
    else if($("#mobile").val().length >= 1){
    $("#mobilesize").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].mobilesize+"</p>");
    }
  }
```

$("#mobile") indicates an input field Id

Any Ideas are warm welcome

Comment: javascript array index start from 0 to length-1;

Comment: thanks @xff1874.I know that one .But I have Missed that thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use only less than in tour condition here. because it start form 0,1,2,....

```
for(var i =0;i<size;i++)
```

you have length 6, but when fetching last then this should be

```
data.validation[5].user
```

You Correct code should be:

```
  var size = data.validation.length;

    for(var i =0;i<size;i++){
    if(data.validation[i].user){
     $("#username").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].user+"</p>");
      }
      if($("#mobile").val().length == 0){
        $("#mobilesize").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].mobile+"</p>");
        }
        else if($("#mobile").val().length >= 1){
        $("#mobilesize").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].mobilesize+"</p>");
        }
      }
```

Comment: ah..I don't Know how I missed that.Great! And I am Sorry for that I tried to vote But less reputation @Siddique Mahsud

Answer (score 1):

Check your array structure:

```
var data = {validation:[
{"user":"user may not be empty"},
{"date":"Date may not be null"},
{"mobile":"passengerMobile may not be empty"},
{"mobileSize":"passengerMobile size must be greater than 11"},
{"name":"passengerName may not be empty"},
{"nameSize":"passengerName size must be between 2 and 30"},
 ]};
```

this is like (pseudo code):

```
data = object
data.validation = array
data.validation[0] = object
data.validation[0].user = "user may not be empty"
data.validation[1].user = undefined!!
data.validation[2].user = undefined!!
data.validation[3].user = undefined!!
```

So you have to change your structure..

Comment: Thanks for an Nice Information In Structure & quick response too.

Answer (score 0):

For some of the values in the validation you do not have "user" hence you getting undefined.

Please use this code to avoid such issues:

```
if(typeof data.validation[i].user != "undefined" && data.validation[i].user){
    $("#username").html("<p>"+data.validation[i].user+"</p>");
 }
```